# Override template for module: /vendor/magento/offline-payments/

Tags: magento2, template, theme

I want to override a template located here:

`(magento_dir)/vendor/magento/module-offline-payments/view/frontend/web/template/payment/purchaseorder-form.html`

I have done the override path liks this, but it is not working:

`(magento_dir)/app/design/frontend/(VendorName)/(ThemeName)/Magento_Offline-Payments/view/frontend/web/template/payment/purchaseorder-form.html`

I have already done this with Magento checkout module and it worked like the below:

Source path:
`(magento_dir)/vendor/magento/module-checkout/...`

My override path:
`(magento_dir)/app/design/frontend/(VendorName)/(ThemeName)/Magento_Checkout/...`

My current issue now is how I can translate "module-offline-payments" to something that works for the override path.

Can someone help?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just found the answer. Here it is if someone is looking for it too.

"module-offline-payments" should be translated as "Magento_OfflinePayments" as the following:

`(magento_dir)/app/design/frontend/(VendorName)/(ThemeName)/Magento_OfflinePayments/web/template/payment/purchaseorder-form.html`

Just had a looked at the following file to see how magento itself was registering its own module:
`<magento_dir>/vendor/module-offline-payments/registration.php`

The module was registered as `"Magento_OfflinePayments"`

Answer (score 0):

In theme module-overrides you can omit the `view/frontend` folders in the path, making the path to your overwrite file as follows:

`(magento_dir)/app/design/frontend/(VendorName)/(ThemeName)/Magento_OfflinePayments/web/template/payment/purchaseorder-form.html`