# module-customer phtml override

Tags: magento-2.0

I'm new to magento 2 and i have a question, how can i override the module module-customer with my own .phtml files?

I tried several searches but i cant find anything, i have tried the following but they didnt work even after i flushed the cached en upgrade from the console.

> Magento_Customer\templates
>
> Magento_Customer\view\frontend\templates

I did forgot the capitals.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override template for module: /vendor/magento/offline-payments/](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/143809/override-template-for-module-vendor-magento-offline-payments)

Comment: Do you have your own theme implemented?
If so `app/design/frontend/<your_package>/<your_theme>/Magento_Customer/templates/<path_to_phtml_file>` will do the override.

Comment: Yes i did implemented my own theme, i did place the files in the directory but it didnt work. i looks like its working now, thanks for you sugestion.

Answer (score 0):

change `Magento_customer` to `**Magento_Customer**`

Comment: I did forgot the capitals in my topic, so thats not the solution! thanks